# How to Capture Multiple Images Using Direct Show

Tags: c#, windows

I am using Direct Show dll using web cam c#(Windows Application)
 [image]

when i click on capture button call :

```
capture.FrameEvent2 += new Capture.HeFrame(CaptureDone);



private void CaptureDone(System.Drawing.Bitmap e)
        {
            if (Captured == true)
            {
                capture.FrameEvent2 -= new Capture.HeFrame(CaptureDone); return;
            }
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                bitmap = e;
                DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;
                string a = localDate.ToString("ddMMMyyyy");
                ImageCount = ImageCount + 1;
                Image old = pictureBox1.Image;
                pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
                StoreImage(pictureBox1.Image);
                string ImageName = "";
                ImageFormat imageFormat = null;
                //Please Change these to opdno
                string regno = txtOpdno.Text;
                string filePath = Application.StartupPath + "\\SonoImage\\" + regno + "";
                if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
                    ImageName = Convert.ToString(ImageCount) + "-" + Convert.ToString(a);
                    filePath = filePath + "\\" + ImageName + ".Jpeg";
                }
                else
                {
                    ImageName = Convert.ToString(ImageCount) + "-" + Convert.ToString(a);
                    filePath = filePath + "\\" + ImageName + ".Jpeg";
                }
                bitmap.Save(filePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                Captured = true;
        }
```

Everythig is work properly but suddenly create :

Object is Currently in use elsewhere
can any one answer me why creating this type of error ?
How to stop this ?